# How to install Hokuyo laser driver on Indigo

Tags: ros, hokuyo-node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I can intall the drivers for the Hokuyo laser range finders on ROS Fuerte by

```
$ sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-laser-drivers
```

But how can I install the same drivers on the ROS Indigo?
I can not find the package including hokuyo_node on ROS Indigo.
I have down loaded the source code of hokuyo_node in the website http://wiki.ros.org/hokuyo_node?distro=groovy,but I do not know how to use it to install the driver.
Could any one give me some advice. Any help is much appreciated!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213061/how-to-install-hokuyo-laser-driver-on-indigo/) by [redskydeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/22936/redskydeng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 118 on 2015-07-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What you are looking for is `hokuyo_node` package, `ros-indigo-hokuyo-node`. A [quick Google search](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=hokuyo+node) shows this:

http://wiki.ros.org/hokuyo_node

But most probably you would like to move to the newest drivers: http://wiki.ros.org/urg_node

---

Originally posted by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) with karma: 1305 on 2015-07-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [redskydeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/22936/redskydeng/) on 2015-07-09**:
Thanks,Javi V.
I have installed the hokuyo_node package as you mentioned and the lidar runs well.
Thanks for your help!

**Comment by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) on 2015-07-09**:
I'm happy that helped you. Would you mind to accept the answer (and upvote if you want)?